# Issues with scala-tools.org and goodstuff.im

Tags: maven

```
➜ repo-data git:(master) mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building pool-data 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/net/alchim31/maven/scala-maven-plugin/3.2.0/scala-maven-plugin-3.2.0.pom
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/alchim31/maven/scala-maven-plugin/3.2.0/scala-maven-plugin-3.2.0.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/alchim31/maven/scala-maven-plugin/3.2.0/scala-maven-plugin-3.2.0.pom (16 KB at 30.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.pom
Jan 19, 2017 4:34:36 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://blog.goodstuff.im:80: Connection reset
```

Every dependency that is pointed at `scala-tools.org` ends up having connection issues with `blog.goodstuff.im`

But [scala-tools was shutdown a long time ago](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:S2pMPVituWUJ:blog.goodstuff.im/no-i-don-t-owe-you-scala-tools-org+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)

Note: scala-tools is owned by david pollak of goodstuff.im

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove scala-tools.org from the repositories listed in the project (pom.xml, settings.xml,...), it is was down several ago (I'm its co-creator). scala-maven-plugin (I'm the owner) is available on maven central and jcenter.